Bitrix - обязательное поле в настройках кастомного модуля
Вопрос в сабе, как сделать обязательное поле на странице настроек кастомного модуля (файл .description)? Сделал поле Select но битрикс дает сохранить его с пустым значением.
'CUSTOM_SUBJECT' => [
        'NAME' => Loc::getMessage('CUSTOM_SUBJECT_TITLE'),
        'DESCRIPTION' => Loc::getMessage('CUSTOM_SUBJECT_DESCRIPTION'),
        'SORT' => 141,
        'GROUP' => Loc::getMessage('CUSTOM_GROUP'),
        'INPUT' => [
            'TYPE' => 'ENUM',
            'OPTIONS' => $subjectValues
        ]
    ],


Не нашел ничего похожего в документации. Можете конечно попробовать 'REQUIRED' => 'Y'. Но вероятнее всего вам придётся вручную писать валидацию для нужного вам поля с выводом ошибки в случае если тот не заполнен.

'REQUIRED' => 'Y' не сработало. вроде такое простое правило но нигде нет информации. про собственный валидатор уже прочитал, видимо из-за пары полей придется еще валидатор писать
